# Linux Container on Android without Root

Tags: android, lxc

Is it possible to start a linux container on a android device without rooting the device?

If so, what would be the best way to go about that? Any hints would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at that? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZWy2g9YY30

Comment: Thanks for your response! Interesting stuff, but Stéphane talks about rebuilding the kernel, so you definitely will have to root the device :-/

Comment: That's correct. It's a interesting topic but I have 0 experience with LXC so I just read into the mail groups. A very recent post announced public build for Android: (http://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2013-December/006517.html) But it doesn't sound like you can work around changing the kernel.